# Spring Integration SpEL for Header evaluation

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to evaluate JMSHeader for Spring Integration message using SpEL but it seems to be evaluating to false always even though message has header stamped as true

`<si:router expression="headers.jms_redelivered.equals(T(java.lang.Boolean).FALSE) ? 'channel1' : 'channel2' />`

```
JMSXDeliveryCount=10, jms_redelivered=true
```

Can some one please comment what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
@Test
public void testRedeliveredHeaderWithSpEL() throws JMSException {
    DefaultJmsHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultJmsHeaderMapper();
    javax.jms.Message jmsMessage = new StubTextMessage() {
        @Override
        public boolean getJMSRedelivered() throws JMSException {
            return true;
        }
    };
    Map<String, Object> headers = mapper.toHeaders(jmsMessage);
    assertNotNull(headers.get(JmsHeaders.REDELIVERED));

    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.addPropertyAccessor(new MapAccessor());
    Expression expression =
            parser.parseExpression("jms_redelivered.equals(T(java.lang.Boolean).FALSE) ? 'channel1' : 'channel2'");
    assertEquals("channel2", expression.getValue(context, headers, String.class));

}
```

You really should be sure that you don't lose `headers` before your `<router>`.

Maybe you use some `<transformer>` before `<router>` which returns whole `Message<?>` istead of just `payload` ?

Comment: Thanks Artem.  Does not work for me. I am doing wire-tap on the router channel to log to see if I am getting the required header(s) and that looks to be logging with expected header(s) including jms_redelivered.

Not sure if it is just the config going wrong. I have worked around using code but would have preferred using config.

Comment: Your Spring Integration version?

Comment: 4.0.2 SI and 4.0.5 Spring. Thanks

Comment: OK. Let's determine what is your goal! Now it sounds like `if  jms_redelivered header is equal to 'FALSE' return 'channel1' otherwise - 'channel2'`. Your position?